# Links in jQuery Accordion Headers using live click

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

Ok so this one is pretty simple putting a live click vs a click affects the ability of the maccordion to follow the same behavior in both. The line being discussed is " **$(".maccordion h3 input").live('click', function () {**".

All i want is the basic you click the button maccordion doesn't do anything click anywhere else in the header and it follows the normal animation.

EDIT: just to add I have tried adding e.stopImmediatePropagation(); and e.stopPropagation(); Niether does anything. Also I have to use live because the code being inserted is created on the fly and brought in through ajax.

```
<div class="maccordion">
<h3><input type='button' value='cick'></h3>
<ul>
    <li><a href="/custom.html">Custom</a>
</ul>
<h3><a href="/account">Account</a></h3>
<ul>
    <li><a href="/account/avatar.html">Avatar</a>
</ul>
```

```
$(function () {

    //Turn the div into an accordion
    $(".maccordion").maccordion({
        header: 'h3'
    });

    //capture the click on the a tag
    $(".maccordion h3 input").live('click', function () {
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: working for me http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/gknsH/ changed `.live()` to `.on()`

Comment: write that as a answer and you get it mate thanks for that. Umm.. can you tell me the difference?

Answer (score 0):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/gknsH/)

changed [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) to [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$(function () {

    //Turn the div into an accordion
    $(".maccordion").accordion({
        header: 'h3'
    });

    //capture the click on the a tag
    $(".maccordion h3 input").on('click', function () {
        return false;
    });
});
```

**As of jQuery 1.7**, the `.live()` method is deprecated. Use `.on()` to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of `jQuery` should use `.delegate()` in preference to `.live()`.

This method provides a means to attach delegated event handlers to the document element of a page, which simplifies the use of event handlers when content is dynamically added to a page. See the discussion of direct versus delegated events in the `.on()` method for more information.

Rewriting the `.live()` method in terms of its successors is straightforward; these are templates for equivalent calls for all three event attachment methods:

```
$(selector).live(events, data, handler);                // jQuery 1.3+
$(document).delegate(selector, events, data, handler);  // jQuery 1.4.3+
$(document).on(events, selector, data, handler);        // jQuery 1.7+
```